# What is “%20” as a string in curl data?

Tags: java, curl

I came across cURL request with parameter as `..&searchText=sweet%20red%20wine'...`

tried googling for `%20` in this but couldn't get exact answer. What is this and why is it used ?

Comment: it's how a space is represented. sweet red wine -> sweet%20red%20wine

Comment: it's a space. first link in google

Comment: refer to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: it means space.

Comment: space, the final frontier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `HTML` encoding and `%20` represents the space character.

The string `"searchText=sweet%20red%20wine"` equates to `"searchText=sweet red wine"`

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's Space.

> Sweet Red Wine

[Look Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)